# Selecting sql records within a time period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the image below, all negative `ContributionAmount` are refunds made and also positive values are payment made by the member.
I want to select for only a particular year all the refunds made and all the contributions made, so I created the query below. But I do not feel comfortable with the query, it does not feel professional and I feel there is a better way to do this especially for performance. Plus when I want to get the information for a particular member, I have to add an additional `WHERE` statement in each subquery.

So my question is how do I build a better query so that I do not have to duplicate codes like that and so that the query works better, I would really appreciate all answers. Thanks..

```
ContributionID MemberID ContributionAmount ContributionDate
             1        2           5000.000 2014-01-31
             2        2          10000.000 2013-12-31
             3        2          15000.000 2014-07-31
             4        3         115000.000 2014-07-22
             5        3          40000.000 2014-07-09
             6        2         115000.000 2014-07-14
             7        2           5000.000 2014-01-31
             8        2           5000.000 2015-01-31
             9        2           5000.000 2014-12-31
            10        2           5000.000 2014-02-28 
            11        3  3000000000000.000 2014-07-31
            12        2         115000.000 2014-07-21
            13        2           5000.000 2014-07-31
            14        3          -15000.000 2013-07-31
```

.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(ca.`ContributionAmount`) 
    FROM contributions_account ca
    WHERE ca.`ContributionAmount` < 0
    AND YEAR(ca.`ContributionDate`) ='2013'
)AS TotatlRefund,
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(ca.`ContributionAmount`) 
    FROM contributions_account ca
    WHERE ca.`ContributionAmount` > 0
    AND YEAR(ca.`ContributionDate`) ='2013'
)AS TotalContribution,
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(ca.`ContributionAmount`) 
    FROM contributions_account ca
    WHERE YEAR(ca.`ContributionDate`) ='2013'
)AS ContributionBalance
```

Comment: removed `sql-server` tag because the non-standard backticks clearly indicate MySQL

Comment: Datatype of ContributionDate?

Comment: Datatype COntributionDate is Date

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN ContributionAmount >= 0 THEN 0 ELSE ContributionAmount END) TotalRefund,
 SUM(CASE WHEN ContributionAmount <= 0 THEN 0 ELSE ContributionAmount END) TotalContribution,
 SUM(ContributionAmount) ContributionBalance
  FROM contributions_account
 WHERE YEAR(ContributionDate) ='2013'
```

For added performance and ability to use an index on `ContributionDate`, change the `WHERE` to:

```
WHERE ContributionDate BETWEEN '2013' AND '2014'
```

As `MySQL` treats `Date`s as strings this comparison works. I believe using the `YEAR` function on the column stops the query from using the index.

Comment: Yeah I tried this already, It returns more than one row of the same data, the number of rows it returns equals the rows returned from the where clause, did not feel right either

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge Really? It should only return one row.

Comment: @JamesOkpeGeorge See edit.. apologies, in my haste I messed up a few names.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN ca.`ContributionAmount` < 0 THEN ca.`ContributionAmount` ELSE 0 END) AS TotatlRefund,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ca.`ContributionAmount` > 0 THEN ca.`ContributionAmount` ELSE 0 END) AS TotalContribution,
        SUM(ca.`ContributionAmount`) AS ContributionBalance
FROM    contributions_account ca
WHERE   YEAR(ca.`ContributionDate`) = '2013'
```

Comment: Yeah, that won't work, you can't put the `SUM` inside one condition of a `CASE` like that and expect it to know what to do across the whole group.

Comment: And now you have duplicated my answer, albeit with a few corrections I missed.

Comment: No worries, to be fair, mine didn't work as written!